# Determining geometry/topology from a Line Element

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, topology

Is it possible given a line element, to determine its geometry? 
For example whether the line element $ds^2$ of a 2D surface corresponds to $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $S^2$ geometry?

Comment: When you say geometry, do you really mean topology?

Comment: Apparently so, given the approved answer.

Comment: Isn't differential geometry ~ differential topology? So then perhaps nomenclature is a little more loose?

Comment: @SamuraiMelon You might argue that adding "differential" makes them more closely related, but they're still quite different.  I've added a little section to the end of my answer to discuss this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific to your example, the simplest thing would probably be to just integrate the [area element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element#Area_element_of_a_surface) (square-root of the determinant of the metric) and see if the result is finite or infinite.  If it's infinite, you have $\mathbb{R}^2$; if it's finite, you have $S^2$.  Of course, there may be more options than just those two.  For example, $\mathbb{R} \times I$ would also have infinite area, and a torus would also have finite area.  So if you have more options, you'll need more tools to distinguish them.

Now, in general, the *geometry* of a manifold is well described using the curvature of its metric — as G. Smith said.  But it seems to me that the question may really be trying to get at *topology* instead, because — at least locally — the geometry of any given surface can look just like the geometry of many other surfaces.  It's only when you look at things globally that you can really distinguish between different types of surfaces — i.e., different topologies.  And for this, there are very useful results.

The main one that springs to mind is the [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem), which gives you the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) of your surface.  The hard part here is computing the [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature).  Generally, I expect the easiest approach would be to use [the formula involving Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#cite_ref-8).  That gets integrated over your surface, with another integral over any boundaries of your surface — which are presumably obvious from the specification of the line element.  Unfortunately, this only applies to compact surfaces, so if you get an infinite result for the total area, it's not going to help much.

There are many ways to go beyond this simple analysis.  For example, the [Atiyah–Singer index theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem), mostly generalizes the G-B theorem, and gives you many more possible ways of computing topological quantities.  Broadly speaking, it's fair to say that similar problems have inspired numerous branches of mathematics — most directly, homotopy, homology, and cohomology theory — though not all of these will relate directly to the question, which specifically cites the line element as the quantity of interest.  But the point I'm trying to make is that there's no magic bullet even for classifying the topology of a manifold.

---

Now, as for the distinction between geometry and topology, the basic difference is that geometry deals with local features, whereas topology deals with global features.  Another way the distinction can be made is to look at the features that you're talking about: if they could vary continuously (e.g., the Ricci curvature scalar), then you classify the problem as geometry; if they can only vary discretely (e.g., the Euler characteristic), then you classify it as topology.  It's also true that when we talk about operations that change geometry, we tend to talk about continuous deformations; whereas continuous deformations don't change topology and so we talk about operations like poking holes in surfaces or gluing surfaces together (which are both discrete operations, mathematically).

When you talk about *differential* topology and *differential* geometry, the distinction is a little bit less obvious — especially in practical usage — but the basic rules are the same.  Essentially, the reason that the distinction is less obvious in this case is that differential topology *uses* local information to derive global results.  And so, many of the results you see in one are closely related to results in the other.

Frankly, I don't think anyone tends to get *too* bent out of shape about classifying things as one or the other; it's all closely related math.  But the reason I bring it up here is because it does actually make a difference in terms of what you're asking about.  If you ask specifically about the *geometry* of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S^2$, it's entirely correct and reasonable for G. Smith to think that you're literally talking about the usual space with exactly zero curvature everywhere and the usual space with exactly constant nonzero curvature everywhere, respectively.  And indeed, that makes the question much simpler.  But personally I tend to think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S^2$ as specifications of topologies, where the geometry may be far more complicated.  For example, a surface with topology $\mathbb{R}^2$ may have nonzero curvature everywhere, whereas a surface with topology $S^2$ may have zero curvature across most of its area — which makes it significantly harder to tell them apart with geometrical methods.

Comment: Thank you, very useful and insightful!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. From the line element you can compute the [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) and distinguish $\mathbb{R}^2$, which has zero curvature, from $S^2$, which has nonzero curvature.

Try it! (Use the usual spherical coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$.) You should find that for a sphere of radius *a* the Ricci curvature scalar $R$ formed from the Riemann curvature tensor is the constant $2/a^2$. The sphere thus has positive scalar curvature, and this curvature is the same at each point on its surface.

Comment: Very useful for a quick check, for exactly what I needed. Much appreciated.